# Is it possible to hide/show items in BottomNavigationBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to hide/show items in BottomNavigationBar using Flutter. For example, I have 4 items which are: Home, Profile, Card, Account. I want to hide/show Card page based on value (0/1) from showCard variable. If showCard == 0, the BottomNavigationBar will show Home, Profile and Account only, else, the BottomNavigationBar will show Home, Profile, Card and Account. Below is my code.

```
return Scaffold(
    body: PageView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: _pageController,
      children: <Widget>[
        //homePage
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  new BoxShadow(blurRadius: 15.0, color: Colors.blue)
                ],
              ),
              child: homePage,
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: bottomNavigationBar,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        //cardPage
        showCard != 0
        ? Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  new BoxShadow(blurRadius: 15.0, color: Colors.blue)
                ],
              ),
              child: cardPage,
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: bottomNavigationBar,
            ),
          ],
        )
            : Container(),
        //profilePage
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  new BoxShadow(blurRadius: 15.0, color: Colors.blue)
                ],
              ),
              child: profilePage,
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: bottomNavigationBar,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        //accountPage
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  new BoxShadow(blurRadius: 15.0, color: Colors.blue)
                ],
              ),
              child: accountPage,
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: bottomNavigationBar,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
);
```

Below are bottomNavigationBar Widget:

```
Widget get bottomNavigationBar {
return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
    topRight: Radius.circular(40),
    topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
  ),
  child: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        activeIcon: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 30.0, color: Colors.amber),),
            Icon(Icons.account_balance),
          ],
        ),
        icon:  Icon(Icons.account_balance),
        title: Text(
          "home",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        activeIcon: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 30.0, color: Colors.amber),),
            Icon(Icons.card_travel),
          ],
        ),
        icon:  Icon(Icons.card_travel),
        title: Text(
          "card",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        activeIcon: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 30.0, color: Colors.amber),),
            Icon(Icons.panorama),
          ],
        ),
        icon:  Icon(Icons.panorama),
        title: Text(
          "profile",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        activeIcon: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 30.0, color: Colors.amber),),
            Icon(Icons.radio),
          ],
        ),
        icon:  Icon(Icons.radio),
        title: Text(
          "account",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
        ),
      ),
    ],
    selectedItemColor: Colors.greenAccent,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    onTap: onTapped,
    currentIndex: currentTabIndex,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is and it's so simple that when you come from other languages, it's counterintuitive:

Just add an `if` right inside the array:

```
if(showCard != 0)
```

Like this:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(),
      if(showCard != 0) BottomNavigationBarItem(),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(),
    ])
```

You will need Dart 2.3 for this, but that came out more than a year ago, you should use it already.

Comment: Hi @nvoigt ! Thank you. I have add if statement at BottomNavigationBar() as your suggestion. It show Home, Profile and Account only but when I click one of the item, it navigate to wrong page. Let say, I click on Account page, it will navigate to Profile page. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Since you did not post your navigation code here, I cannot :) It's a different question, it might be best to post a *new* question with the code relevant to it.

Comment: Thank you @nvoigt ! It works. My mistake that I point to a wrong page. Thank you for helping me. It works great now! I will mark this as an answer. Have a good day!